# Converting Png to Bmp and bitmap array

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, bmp

I search for my problem solution in SO and I don't find  ( maybe it is not a problem and it works fine just I'm to dump to get it )

I have BMP file that i try to convert into bitmap array. Everything is fine, but i get an output file that looks weird. The file is 16x32, so i should get 512 bit. The final image is black and white, so i should have 512 x 3 ( 3 color bit ) pixels - 1536 pixels with value 0 or 255, but a get 1590 pixels. This 54 pixels have different value than 0 or 255 why ? What is that value and for what bmp file use it ? 
Code: `

```
        long time = 0;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Image img = Image.FromFile("test.png");
        byte[] data;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        data = ms.ToArray();
        watch.Stop();
        time = watch.ElapsedTicks;
        Console.WriteLine(time);
        FileStream file = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);


        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(b); 
        }
        writer.Close();
        file.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();`
```

Code is not nice to read i know but is only for some test 
[image: My image]

Comment: If is probably the [FileHeader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header) for the BMP file. Does it start with "BM"? Look at the Example 1!

Comment: So it look  like if i need to only work with picture in my code i can ignore it ?

Comment: Yes, provided you know that it has the right offset. The length of the offset will vary with some bmp formats.

Comment: Yea so ignore it :) Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say its the fileheader, like TaW already pointed out. According to this website http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html the BMP header size is 54 bytes. If you look at offset 18 and 22, you should see the width and height (16, 32) of your picture.